# How to deploy Celery worker to EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, celery

I have a Django project that I run in an Elastic Beanstalk instance. I added some Celery code to it and created an EC2 instance to host RabbitMQ and the Celery workers, but I don't know how to deploy my app and env to this new EC2 instance. All docs from AWS assume that if you're working with Python you want to use Elastic Beanstalk but I just need a way to put my env and run my workers in a pristine EC2, preferably through the CLI.

Comment: Did you check AWS Code Deploy?

Comment: I would suggest using dockers, if you build a docker once with all that you need you can deploy on any machine you want (ec2) included.